# getNodeInfo() and removeEmployee() not working

Tags: c++

I have included 3 files here, My problem is occurring in my **MainMenu.cpp** file. The two function calls "*void removeEmployee*", and "*NodeInfo getNodeInfo*" are not working the way I intended them to. I was wondering if anyone would be kind enough to show me whats going wrong here, and how I can fix it. All help is apprectiated, as I am new to coding and am currently working on the basics

```
// The MainMenu (.h & .cpp) file contains the function declarations used to 
// present a main menu which allows a user to view, add, and remove employees.
// The list of employees is implemented with a linked list, and most of the
// processing functions get passed a pointer to the first element of the 
// list (Employee* pHead).

#ifndef MAINMENU_H
#define MAINMENU_H

#include <string>

// a struct to represent an Employee (each instance forms a node of a linked list
// used to store employees.
struct Employee {
    int id;
    std::string fname;
    Employee* next;
};

// A struct used to return multiple return values from the getNodeInfo() function.
struct NodeInfo {
    Employee* node; // a pointer to an employee node.
    Employee* parent;   // a pointer to the node prior to the employee node (nullptr if node is at the front)
};

// display the main menu
void displayMainMenu();

// fetch and return an integer from user input
int getInt();

// output a list of all employees to the console
void viewEmployees(Employee* pHead);

// creates a new employee by allocating one from the heap and returning a pointer to it.
Employee* createEmployee(const std::string& fName);

// responsible for creating a new employee node, and adding it to the list
void addNewEmployee(Employee*& pHead, const std::string& fName);

// Searches through the list for a node with the given id.  Returns a nodeInfo struct pointing to the node and its parent.
NodeInfo getNodeInfo(Employee* pHead, int id);

// Removes an employee node with the given id from the list.
void removeEmployee(Employee*& pHead, int id);

// Given an int representing a menu choice, this will determine what should be done for each choice.
bool handleMenuInput(Employee*& pHead, int menuItemSelected);

#endif
```

```
// This file is contains our main() routine which determines where our program execution 
// begins and ends.
#include <iostream>
#include "MainMenu.h"

// Set up a pointer for tracking a linked list of Employees
// Display a menu allowing a user various choices, and process those choices
// Clean up any dynamically allocated memory before finishing
int main()
{
    // a pointer to our linked list of employees.
    Employee* pEmployees = nullptr;

    bool exitMainMenu{ false }; // init to default value
    int menuChoice{ -1 };           // init to a known starting value

    // display the main menu, allow the user to make choices, and handle the input
    do {
        displayMainMenu();
        int menuChoice{ getInt() };
        while (menuChoice == -1) {
            std::cout << "Invalid input.\n";
            displayMainMenu();
            menuChoice = getInt();
        }
        // handle the input, determine if we have an exit condition
        exitMainMenu = handleMenuInput(pEmployees, menuChoice);
    } while (!exitMainMenu);

    // cleanup! - deallocate any employees in our linked list before setting the list to nullptr;
    // TODO

    return 0;
}
```

```
// See comments in MainMenu.h for general details on what each functin does.
#include <iostream>
#include "MainMenu.h"
using namespace std;

// output the menu choices to the console.
void displayMainMenu()
{
    std::cout << "\n";
    std::cout << "--- MENU ---\n";
    std::cout << "1) View Employees\n";
    std::cout << "2) Add Employee\n";
    std::cout << "3) Remove Employee\n";
    std::cout << "0) Exit\n";
    std::cout << "-------------\n";
    std::cout << "Select:";
}


// Attempt to read an int from cin.  
// Check if there was a failure, if so, return -1.
int getInt() {
    int x;
    std::cin >> x;
    if (std::cin.fail()) {
        std::cin.clear();
        std::cin.ignore(32767, '\n');
        x = -1;
    }
    return x;
}


// if pHead is a nullptr:
//    - print a "empty list" message to the user
// if pHead not a nullptr,
// - create a pCurr variable to point to pHead,
// - while pCurr is not a nullptr,
// - print the id and name out to the console
// - set pCurr to point to the next node.
void viewEmployees(Employee* pHead) {
    // TODO
    if (pHead == nullptr) {
        std::cout << "View list is Empty" << endl;
    }
    else {
        Employee* pCurr = pHead;
        while (pCurr != nullptr) {
            std::cout << "Id: " << pCurr->id << " Name: " << pCurr->fname << std::endl;
            pCurr = pCurr->next;
        }
    }
}



// Use a static variable to generate unique employee id's with (initialize it &
// increment it every time this function is called).
// Dynamically allocate memory for an employee struct from the heap.  
// Initialize it with :
// -the unique id,
// -the fName passed in as a paramter,
// -nullptr.
// Return the pointer to the new dynamically allocated Employee.
Employee* createEmployee(const std::string& fName) {
    // TODO

    static int Employee_id = 0;
    Employee_id++;
    Employee* newEmployee = new Employee{ Employee_id ,fName,nullptr };

    return newEmployee;  // replace this, it is only here to allow this to compile
}


// First Create a new employee (by calling createEmployee())
// Insert the new employee at the front of the linked list
// - point the new employee's next pointer to the existing head.
// - point the existing head at the new employee
void addNewEmployee(Employee*& pHead, const std::string& fName) {
    // TODO
    /* 1. allocate node */
    Employee* newEmployee = createEmployee(fName);
    /* 2. put in the data */



    try
    {
        /* 3. Make next of new node as head */
        newEmployee->next = pHead;

        /* 4. move the head to point to the new node */
        pHead = newEmployee;
    }
    catch (exception& e)
    {
        cout << "Exception happened in addNewEmployee" << endl;
    }


}


// Search through the linked list for a node whose id matches the id parameter
// Return a NodeInfo struct to tell the calling function details about your findings.
// Start by initializing its members to nullptr.
// Use an Employee* pCurr var to iterate through the linked list (while pCurr->id != id)
//
// If you find a match,
// set your nodeInfo.node to the node you matched.
// set your nodeInfo.parent to the parent of the node you matched *.
// return nodeInfo
// If no match found simply return nodeInfo as is. (The calling function (removeEmployee())
// should interpret the nullptr vars to mean not found)
//
// (* To track the parent, create a local Employee* pLast, set it to nullptr,
// then update it to point to pCurr right before you move pCurr to point to the
//    next node. If you find a match, pLast will then be pointing to the parent.)
NodeInfo getNodeInfo(Employee* pHead, int id) {
    // TODO
    //to track parent
    Employee* pLast = nullptr;
    Employee* pCurr = pHead;
    int trys = 0;
    //update once move to next node
    do {


        if (pCurr->id == id) {
            return NodeInfo{ pCurr, pLast };
        }
        pLast = pCurr;
        pCurr = pCurr->next;
        trys++;




        if (trys >= 20) {
            std::cout << " over 20 trys";
            return NodeInfo{ nullptr, nullptr };
        }

    } while (pCurr->id != id);










    // temporary return value so that the project will compile
}


// If pHead is a nullptr, then there are no employees to remove, output an error message and return
// Try to find a node with the given id (use getNodeInfo()).
// If not found, output an error message and return
// If found:
// If pHead is the same as the node we found for the id, (it means the node we found is
//    the first one in the list). This is a special case:
// -Set the pHead to node->next (The first param is a reference so that we can,
//   change the address that pHead points to and have it affect the caller).
// -Return the memory of the node we want to delete to the heap
// otherwise
// (the node we found isn't the first one - it should theoretically have a parent)
// -If the parent is a nullptr, print an error message (this should never happen, but we should check)
// -If the parent is not a nullptr
// -Set the parent's next pointer to the next pointer of the node we want to delete
// -Output a "removed id: #" message to the console
// -Deallocate memory from node back to the heap.
void removeEmployee(Employee*& pHead, int id) {
    Employee* pCurr = pHead;
    //1. if phead is nullptr, out error and return
    if (pHead == nullptr) {
        std::cout << "Error in removeEmployee phead is nullptr" << endl;
        return;
    }
    //2. Try to find a node with the given id (use getNodeInfo()).
    NodeInfo nodeFind = getNodeInfo(pHead, id);
    //3. If not found, output an error message and return
    if ((nodeFind.node == nullptr) || (nodeFind.parent == nullptr)) {
        std::cout << "Error in removeEmployee did not find ptr" << endl;
        return;


        //4. If found: only other option
        //5. If pHead is the same as the node we found for the id, (it means the node we found is
        if (pHead == nodeFind.node) {
            pHead->next;
            // -6.Return the memory of the node we want to delete to the heap
            removeEmployee(pHead, id);

            // -7.If the parent is a nullptr, print an error message (this should never happen, but we should check)
            if (nodeFind.parent == nullptr) {
                std::cout << "Error in removeEmployee Parent is a nullptr" << endl;
            }
            else if (nodeFind.parent != nullptr) {
                nodeFind.parent->next;
                std::cout << "removed id: #" << id << endl;
                delete(pCurr);



            }









        }




    }
}

// This function is called when a user picks a selection from the menu.
// It determines what action to take depending on the menuItemSelected, and calls
// the appropriate function.
// Returns true the selection was a request to exit menu, false otherwise.
bool handleMenuInput(Employee*& pHead, int menuItemSelected)
{
    bool exitRequest{ false };

    switch (menuItemSelected)
    {
    case 1:
        std::cout << ">> View Employees:\n";
        viewEmployees(pHead);
        break;
    case 2:
    {
        std::cout << ">> Add Employee:\n";
        std::cout << "Enter first name:";
        std::string fName;
        std::cin >> fName;
        addNewEmployee(pHead, fName);
    }
    break;
    case 3:
        std::cout << ">> Remove Employee:\n";
        std::cout << "Enter id:";
        int id;
        std::cin >> id;
        removeEmployee(pHead, id);
        break;
    case 0:
        std::cout << "Exiting\n";
        exitRequest = true;
        break;
    default:
        std::cout << "Invalid input.\n";
        break;
    }
    return exitRequest;
}
```

Comment: All the descriptions are included in my MainMenu.h file

Comment: i have been trying to fix getNodeInfo but am having a hard time , thats why im here asking for help

Answer (score 0):

I am embedding the instructions into the code to show you where things went wrong in `getNodeInfo`

```
NodeInfo getNodeInfo(Employee* pHead, int id)
{
// Return a NodeInfo struct to tell the calling function details about your findings.
// Start by initializing its members to nullptr.
    NodeInfo result = { nullptr, nullptr };

// (* To track the parent, create a local Employee* pLast, set it to nullptr,
// then update it to point to pCurr right before you move pCurr to point to the
//    next node. If you find a match, pLast will then be pointing to the parent.)
    Employee* pLast = nullptr;

// Use an Employee* pCurr var to iterate through the linked list (while pCurr->id != id)
// NOTE: while pCurr->id != id is where these instructions go wrong and mislead you
    Employee* pCurr = pHead;

// This is what you want to do instead:
    while (pCurr != nullptr) // iterate to the end of the list
    {
// If you find a match,
        if (pCurr->id == id)
        {
// set your nodeInfo.node to the node you matched.
// set your nodeInfo.parent to the parent of the node you matched *.
// return nodeInfo
            result.node = pCurr;
            result.parent = pLast;
            return result;
        }
        pLast = pCurr;
        pCurr = pCurr->next;
    }

// If no match found simply return nodeInfo as is. (The calling function (removeEmployee())
// should interpret the nullptr vars to mean not found)
    return result;
}
```

Now for `removeEmployee`. It's problems are mostly with incomplete instructions (`pHead->next;` doesn't do anything) and misplaced brackets.

```
void removeEmployee(Employee*& pHead, int id)
{
    //1. if phead is nullptr, out error and return
    if (pHead == nullptr)
    {
        std::cout << "Error in removeEmployee phead is nullptr" << endl;
        return;
    }
    //2. Try to find a node with the given id (use getNodeInfo()).
    NodeInfo nodeFind = getNodeInfo(pHead, id);
    //3. If not found, output an error message and return
// NOTE: || (nodeFind.parent == nullptr) makes the later if (nodeFind.parent == nullptr)
// test pointless. It would never be reached. I removed it.
    if ((nodeFind.node == nullptr))
    {
        std::cout << "Error in removeEmployee did not find ptr" << endl;
        return;
    }
    //4. If found: only other option
    //5. If pHead is the same as the node we found for the id, (it means the node we found is
    if (pHead == nodeFind.node)
    {
        Employee * temp = pHead; // need to keep a copy to delete
        pHead = pHead->next; // head is now the next node
        // -6.Return the memory of the node we want to delete to the heap
        delete temp;
        return; // all done might as well exit
    }
    // -7.If the parent is a nullptr, print an error message (this should never happen, but we should check)
    if (nodeFind.parent == nullptr)
    {
        std::cout << "Error in removeEmployee Parent is a nullptr" << endl;
        return; // need to stop if this error happens or the linked list will be broken worse
    }
    nodeFind.parent->next = nodeFind.node->next; // point parent at next node.
                                         // This removes current from the list
    std::cout << "removed id: #" << id << endl;
    delete (nodeFind.node);
}
```

Addendum:

This isn't what the instructor asked for so don't hand this in, but it demonstrates a much better way to write `getNodeInfo` by taking advantage of adding an extra layer of indirection, using a pointer to a next pointer to simultaneously give access to the parent's next pointer AND the found node, if any.

```
Employee** getNodeInfo(Employee*& pHead, int id)
{
    Employee** pCurr = &pHead; // a pointer to a next pointer gives you the next
                               // that needs to be updated (the parent) AND the
                               // note that was found
    while (*pCurr) // while there is a node
    {
        if ((*pCurr)->id == id) //check to see if the current node is the id
        {
            break; // found it. Stop looking
        }
        pCurr = &(*pCurr)->next; // get pointer to current node's next pointer
    }

    return pCurr; // pointer to next of parent node or 
}

void removeEmployee(Employee*& pHead, int id)
{
    Employee ** found = getNodeInfo(pHead, id);
    if (*found == nullptr)
    {
        std::cout << "Error in removeEmployee did not find ptr" << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        Employee * temp = *found; // store pointer to found node for delete
        *found = (*found)->next; // parent's next = found node's next
        delete temp; // remove found node
    }
}
```